# Justification for using $P\{X \leq x\}$ notation in random variables

Tags: probability-theory

So a random variable is formally defined (in my textbook) as follows:

> Let $(\Omega, F, P)$ be a probability space. Random variable $X$ is a function $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies
>   $$(\forall B \in \mathbb{B}) X^{-1}(B) \in F$$

$\mathbb{B}$ being the Borel sigma field/algebra. Then we introduce a theorem which states:

> A random variable $X$ defines a probability space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{B}, P_x)$ where $P_x$ is a function $P_x:\mathbb{B} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $$P_x(B) = P(X^{-1}(B))$$

This part is still okay, and it's relatively easy to prove (the only thing that needs proving is that $P_x$ is in fact a probability function). We also mentioned that the function $P_x$ is called the distribution of the random variable $X$.

Now, since $P_x$ takes a Borel set on input, which makes it impossible to plot, we introduce the probability distribution function as $F_x:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as 
$$(\forall x \in \mathbb{R}) F_x(x) = P_x((-\infty, x])$$

Okay this makes sense as well. We take $x$, we make a Borel set out of it as $(-\infty, x]$ and apply the probability $P_x$ to it. However, the line that I wrote above also contains
$$ = P\{X \leq x\} $$

Alright, before I even started learning the theoretical aspects of probability I've done a lot of problems. I am familiar with this notation and I know how it's used in practice. However, now that I've seen how everything is defined 'below' I don't really see how we're "allowed" to write something like that. One option could be that this is just a convention so we don't have to write a lot. On the other hand, some further definitions and theorems use this notation in a very formal sense, so that's why I think I'm missing something here.

So we've got:
$$P_x((-\infty, x])$$ which, by definition, should be
$$P(X^{-1}((-\infty, x]) )$$

if we go into it a little more we could write it as (I think):

$$P(\{\omega \in \Omega| X(\omega) \in (-\infty, x]\})$$

But I'm still nowhere near this notation.

So, is there any formal justification for this way of writing it, or is it just a convention we use to make it more readable?

Thanks.

Comment: What is wrong with a little abbreviation if it doesn't cause any confusion ? Do you have a situation where the notation $P(X \leq x)$ can be misunderstood?

Comment: Didn't say anything was wrong with it, just checking whether I'm missing some formal meaning of the way it's written. So it is just an abbreviation after all?

Comment: Yes. it is just an abbreviation for $P(\{\omega: X(\omega) \leq x\})$.

Comment: Alright, thanks for clearing it up.